# Excel VBA "AxisBetweenCategories" property missing in ChartSpace

Tags: excel, vba, charts, userform

I vainly try to set the `AxisBetweenCategories` property to False in a Userform ChartSpace. It is a clusteredBarChart. I did the same manually in a normal chart and it worked. Recording a Marco generated the code with the `AxisBetweenCategories` property. Why can't I use it in the Userform ChartSpace.

```
me.ChartSpace1.Charts(0).Axes(0).AxisBetweenCategories = False 'doesn't work
```

What do I miss?
Thanks

Comment: The properties and methods available for a `ChChart` are **not** the same as those avaialble to a `Chart`, so the macro recorder won't be much help here... let m try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Chart" inside a `ChartSpace` object is of type `ChChart` and the same properties and methods you use on a `Chart` (worksheet, or chartsheet) do not translate directly so unfortunately the macro recorder won't be of much help, you will have to turn to good old fashioned debugging, trial & error.

I use the Locals window to examine the objects for a hint at the object model (that's how I observe the type is `ChChart`, etc.)

[image]

You can then look at the available properties and [Google *usually* can point you in the right direction](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=&ie=UTF-8&q=ChAxes%20crosses%20between%20category), like [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa206363(v=office.11).aspx).  Exploring the intellisense, I see that there are really limited options that are not the same as the `Chart` objects on a worksheet.

After all of that, this is probably not the answer you want to hear, but **it can't be done the way you want it to be done**.

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.office.developer.web.components/3cLJXRnTbQw/iXMAWVBYwPEJ) seems to verify that observation and suggests that while some things are the same, others can simply not be rendered the same way.

> [Chartspace Charts do] not have the refined axis crossing as Excel
>   does.  Features  between the two will be similar in certain area and
>   not in others

And a [similar example from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa206364(v=office.11).aspx):

> This example sets the category axis to cross the value axis at value zero (0) in the chart workspace.

```
Sub SetCrossingValue()
    Dim chConstants
    Dim axValueAxis
    Dim axCategoryAxis

    Set chtContants = ChartSpace1.Constants

    Set axValueAxis = ChartSpace1.Charts(0).Axes(chConstants.chAxisPositionValue)
    Set axCategoryAxis = ChartSpace1.Charts(0).Axes(chConstants.chAxisPositionCategory)

    axValueAxis.CrossingAxis = axCategoryAxis

    axCategoryAxis.CrossesAtValue = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the detailed answer. Please give me some time to check that out before I accept. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Ok, I need to change my approach then. I'll definitely use the Locals window the next time. Thanks for the hint.